# Having an attributed called Model in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model called "Product" with some fields: color, price and model.

I want to have getters and setters for these values:

```
class Product {
  public function setColor();
  public function setPrice();
  public function getColor();
  public function getPrice();  
}

$product = new Product();
$product->setColor($color);
$product->setPrice($price);
```

However, I cannot do the same for the model attribute since it is a reserved word:

```
class Product {
  public function getModel(); // This breaks things
}
```

In Eloquent Models have static functions "getModel".

Is there a way to workaround this, so I can have an attribute "model" in a ... Model?

Comment: If i'm understanding well what ou want, you've got to check around entity relationships

Comment: I'm not talking about relationships. I might have failed to describe the problem accurately. I'll update it.

Comment: Well ok i got it. Then no it's not possible to override this getter. If laravel tells it's not allowed, that's for a reason. But anyway why are you doing getters and setters ?

Comment: You can use accessors & mutators from Laravel. [Laravel Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).
You just create function called `getFirstNameAttribute($value)` in your model and then you can use `$myModel->first_name` - it will call your function `getFirstNameAttribute(...)`. Same approach is available for mutators `setFirstNameAttribute($value)`.

Comment: Thanks. But we are trying to keep the system agnostic regarding what ORM we are using. Also for testing it's harder to test properties than methods.